# How to define a method for which the returntype is based on types of argument and type parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

I want to define a method which has a returntype that is dependent on the type of the argument passed to that method and the type parameter of the enclosing trait. It's quite difficult to describe in words what I mean, so below are some snippets to explain.

I have a few building blocks

```
// This is the target of a binding
trait BindableValue[T] {
  def set(value: T): Unit

  // this is the method I am strugling with
  def bindTo[S](o: S) = ???
}

// This will dispatch events of type T
trait Observable[T]

// This represents a value of type T that will 
// dispatch events if the value changes
trait ObservableValue[T] extends Observable[T] {
  def value: T
}

// An Observable can be converted to an optional ObservableValue
object ObservableValue {
  implicit def wrap[T](o:Observable[T]):ObservableValue[Option[T]] = 
    new ObservableValue[Option[T]] {
      val value = None
    }
}
```

A binding has a source and a target and exists for two kinds:

1. Complete: both source and target type parameters are the same
2. Incomplete: source and target type parameters are different

...

```
trait Binding[S, T] {
  def source: ObservableValue[S]
  def target: BindableValue[T]
}

class CompleteBinding[T](
  val source: ObservableValue[T], 
  val target: BindableValue[T]) extends Binding[T, T]

class IncompleteBinding[S, T](
  val source: ObservableValue[S], 
  val target: BindableValue[T]) extends Binding[S, T]
```

I can construct the following instances.

```
val bindable1 = new BindableValue[Int] { def set(value:Int) = {} }
val property1 = new ObservableValue[Int] { def value = 0 }
val property2 = new ObservableValue[String] { def value = "" }

val bindable2 = new BindableValue[Option[Int]] { def set(value:Option[Int]) = {} }
val event1 = new Observable[Int] {}
val event2 = new Observable[String] {}
```

Now I want to use those instances like this:

```
// 'a' should be of type CompleteBinding
val a = bindable1 bindTo property1

// 'b' should be of type IncompleteBinding
val b = bindable1 bindTo property2

// 'c' should be of type CompleteBinding
val c = bindable2 bindTo event1

// 'd' should be of type IncompleteBinding
val d = bindable2 bindTo event2
```

I can't figure out how to define the method `bindTo` so that it will compile the above 4 lines and have the correct concrete type for all values. I simply miss knowledge about the Scala type system.

Allthough I would love to find a solution I also want to understand how to get to such a solution myself in the future. If you have a solution for the above problem, could you also point me to some sources that I could use to educate myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typeclasses can help you to solve the problem. First let's define simple trait:

```
trait Composeable[A, B, R] {
    def compose(a: A, b: B): R
}
```

It just takes `a` and `b` and composes them in some other container of type `R`.

Now let's define 2 concrete implementations of it for `CompleteBinding` and `IncompleteBinding` in companion object and also make them implicit:

```
object Composeable extends LowPriorityComposables {
    implicit def  comCommplete[T] = new Composeable[ObservableValue[T], BindableValue[T], CompleteBinding[T]] {
        def compose(a: ObservableValue[T], b: BindableValue[T]) = new CompleteBinding(a, b)
    }
}

trait LowPriorityComposables {
    implicit def  comIncommplete[S, T] = new Composeable[ObservableValue[S], BindableValue[T], IncompleteBinding[S, T]] {
        def compose(a: ObservableValue[S], b: BindableValue[T]) = new IncompleteBinding(a, b)
    }
}
```

As you can see, implementation is pretty straightforward. It just takes `ObservableValue` and `BindableValue` and combines then in `Binding`. I separated them in different traits because generally they both can be used, if you observe and bind the same value of some type `T` (the case of `CompleteBinding`). By extracting `comIncommplete` in separate trait I told compiler, that it should use it in case if no other suitable implicit was found. In other word you are telling compiler to always try to apply `CompleteBinding` and if it cannot be done, then `IncompleteBinding` should be applied.

The only thing remains is to define `bindTo` method that uses `Composeable` type class:

```
def bindTo[S, R](o: ObservableValue[S])(implicit ev: Composeable[ObservableValue[S], BindableValue[T], R]): R = 
    ev.compose(o, this)
```

Here I say, that the first argument is `o` which is some `ObservableValue` that contains values of type `S`, but I also want compile to find an evidence, that there exist some implicit, that proves, that I can compose `ObservableValue[S]` with `BindableValue[T]`. When  i have such evidence, I just compose observable with this (bindable). As you can see, type parameter `R` is something like free variable - compiler can figure it out but itself, so you always have concreate type information returned from the `bindTo` method.

Now all you test cases should compile just fine:

```
val a: CompleteBinding[Int] = bindable1 bindTo property1
val b: IncompleteBinding[String, Int] = bindable1 bindTo property2
val c: CompleteBinding[Option[Int]] = bindable2 bindTo event1
val d: IncompleteBinding[Option[String], Option[Int]] = bindable2 bindTo event2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I needed to know. I heard of type classes and even watched a video about them. My brain just didn't know how to use them in this case. I will go and learn more about those. Thanks again!