# Logic operators for non-Boolean types in Scala

Tags: scala, boolean, type-safety

I like the concise code that can be written using boolean operators rather than conditionals in (usually dynamic) languages like Lisp, Python or JavaScript, as in the typical:

```
x = someString or "default string"
```

vs

```
if someString:
    x = someString
else:
    x = "default string"
```

In Scala I've thought something like:

```
object Helpers {
  case class NonBooleanLogic[A](x: A) {
    // I could overload the default && and ||
    // but I think new operators are less 'surprise prone'
    def |||(y: => A)(implicit booleanConversion: A => Boolean) = if (x) x else y
    def &&&(y: => A)(implicit booleanConversion: A => Boolean) = if (!x) x else y
  }

  implicit def num2bool(n : Int) = n != 0

  implicit def seq2bool(s : Seq[Any]) = !s.isEmpty

  implicit def any2bool(x : Any) = x != null

  implicit def asNonBoolean[T](x: T) = NonBooleanLogic(x)
}

object SandBox {
  // some tests cases...

  1 ||| 2                                         //> res2: Int = 1

  val x : String = null                           //> x  : String = null
  x ||| "hello"                                   //> res3: String = hello

  //works promoting 2 to Float
  1.0 &&& 2                                       //> res4: Double = 2.0

  //this doesn't work :(
  1 &&& 2.0
}
```

But two concerns arise:

1. How to make it work for types that have a common ancestor without reverting to `Any` type?
2. This is so cool that somebody else must have done it before, probably in a better documented, tested and comprehensive library. Where to find it?

Comment: BTW this is more idiomatic: `val x = if (someString != null && someString.size() > 0) someString else "default string";`

Comment: it was meant to be JavaScript, not Scala

Comment: Your second snippet can be written as `val x = Option(someString).filterNot(_.isEmpty).getOrElse("default string")` or `val x = if(someString != null && someString.size() > 0) someString else "default string"`

Comment: I think I'll change the snippets to Python to not answer the same thing over and over again xD

Answer (score 3):

I will just stick to Option[T]... which is more idiomatic to Scala. I also often used it in validation, ex: In a web form, sometimes an empty string should not be considered as a valid user input.

For example, if you think a null String / String with zero length(`""`) is false, any null reference is also false, and any numeric zero is false, you could write the following implicit defs.

```
object MyOptionConverter
{
    implicit def toOption(any: AnyRef) = Option(any)
    implicit def toOption(str: String) = {
        Option(str).filter(_.length > 0)
    }

    implicit def toOption[T](value: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T]): Option[T] = {
        Option(value).filter(_ != 0)
    }
}

import MyOptionConverter._

println(1 getOrElse 10)   // 1
println(5.5 getOrElse 20) // 5.5
println(0 getOrElse 30)  // 30
println(0.0 getOrElse 40) // 40
println((null: String) getOrElse "Hello")  // Hello
println((null: AnyRef) getOrElse "No object") // No object
println("World" getOrElse "Hello")
```

And if you really need defined your own operator, convert it to a class that holds a Option[T], and add operator to it.

```
object MyOptionConverter
{
    class MyBooleanLogic[T](x: Option[T], origin: T)
    {
        def |||(defaultValue: T) = x.getOrElse(defaultValue)
        def &&&(defaultValue: T) = x.isDefined match {
            case true  => defaultValue
            case false => origin
        }
    }

    implicit def toOption(any: AnyRef) = {
        new MyBooleanLogic(Option(any), any)
    }
    implicit def toOption(str: String) = {
        new MyBooleanLogic(Option(str).filter(_.length > 0), str)
    }

    implicit def toOption[T](value: T)(implicit num: Numeric[T])= {
        new MyBooleanLogic(Option(value).filter(_ != 0), value)
    }
}

import MyOptionConverter._

println(1 ||| 10)   // 1
println(5.5 ||| 20) // 5.5
println(0 ||| 30)  // 30
println(0.0 ||| 40) // 40
println((null: String) ||| "Hello")  // Hello
println((null: AnyRef) ||| "No object") // No object
println("World" ||| "Hello")


println(1 &&& 10)   // 10
println(5.5 &&& 20) // 20
println(0 &&& 30)  // 0
println(0.0 &&& 40) // 0.0
println((null: String) &&& "Hello")  // null
println((null: AnyRef) &&& "No object") // null
println("World" &&& "Hello") // Hello
```

Comment: well, just sticking to `Option` type and `getOrElse` leaves the `and` method a little bit orphaned... and introducing it when creating or overriding the logical operators seems a little bit redundant or even unnecessary :-/ Although I love the implicit `Numeric` conversion! :D

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to come up with something like a Monad.  What you want to do is already built into the language, and is common in idiomatic scala.  I'm not an expert on Monads, but they say an Option is a kind of Monad.

You're specifically asking for the ability to write:

```
val x = someString or "default string"
```

What makes someString evaluate to false?  In most languages, you'd be testing if( someString != null ), and that's what you do in your example.  Idiomatic scala avoids use of null, instead it uses None.

So, in scala syntax, you'd have

```
val someString:Option[String] = getAString()
```

or

```
val someString:Option[String] = Some("whatever")
```

or

```
val someString:Option[String] = None
```

and then you'd have:

```
val x = someString getOrElse "default string"
```

Which is almost exactly what you asked for.

If you want to implement something like this on your own, look at the interface for getOrElse in Option (similar versions exist in Map and other places in the standard library):

```
final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B
```

In this example, the Option someString has a type (i.e. String) represented by A.  B must be an A or a super type of A.  The return type will be B (which might be A).  For example:

```
val x:Option[Int]=1
x getOrElse 1.0 // this will be an AnyVal, not Any.
```

AnyVal is the most-specific common ancestor of Int and Double.  Note that that's AnyVal here, not Any.

If you want it to be Double instead of AnyVal, you need x to be an Option[Double] (or you need another implicit). There's a built-in implicit conversion from Int to Double, but not from Option[Int] to Option[Double].  The implicit conversion is why your 2 gets promoted to a Float, not because of your boolean logic.

I don't think your operators and implicits method is the best solution to this sort of problem.  There are many ways to write concise elegant scala code using Options, filter, exists, map, flatMap, etc, that can handle the kinds of operations you want to perform.

You might find this helpful:

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/ruby/monads-are-not-metaphors

Comment: See also: http://james-iry.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/monads-are-elephants-part-1.html?m=1 - none of the code examples you showed actually rely on Option being a monad. A monad is like an interface; it describes some, but not necessarily all, of what a type can do.

Comment: yeah... and I was answering a specific part of his question.  His more general idea, converting certain values to a weird concept of `false`, and then having some mapping of values to values... seemed related.  I could be wrong about there being any relatedness though.

Answer (score 1):

I have only created a version for the `|||` version. It's to show the concept. The code might be improved, I rushed it a bit.

```
// Create a type that does the conversion, C is the resulting type
trait Converter[A, B, C] {
  def convert(a: A, b: => B)(implicit bool: BooleanConverter[A]): C
}

trait LowerPriorityConverter {
  // We can convert any type as long as we know how to convert A to a Boolean
  // The resulting type should be a supertype of both A and B
  implicit def anyConverter[A <: C, B <: C, C] = new Converter[A, B, C] {
    def convert(a: A, b: => B)(implicit bool: BooleanConverter[A]) = if (a) a else b
  }

  // We can go more specific if we can find a view from B to A
  implicit def aViewConverter[B <% A, A] = anyConverter[A, A, A]
}

object Converter extends LowerPriorityConverter {

  // For Doubles, Floats and Ints we have a specialized conversion as long as the
  // second type is a Numeric

  implicit def doubleConverter[A <: Double: Numeric, B: Numeric] = 
    new Converter[A, B, Double] {
      def convert(a: A, b: => B)(implicit bool: BooleanConverter[A]) =
        if (a) a else implicitly[Numeric[B]].toDouble(b)
    }
  implicit def floatConverter[A <: Float: Numeric, B: Numeric] = 
    new Converter[A, B, Float] {
      def convert(a: A, b: => B)(implicit bool: BooleanConverter[A]) = 
        if (a) a else implicitly[Numeric[B]].toFloat(b)
    }
  implicit def intConverter[A <: Int: Numeric, B: Numeric] = 
    new Converter[A, B, Int] {
      def convert(a: A, b: => B)(implicit bool: BooleanConverter[A]) = 
        if (a) a else implicitly[Numeric[B]].toInt(b)
    }
}

// We have created a typeclass for the boolean converters as well, 
// this allows us to use more generic types for the converters
trait BooleanConverter[A] extends (A => Boolean)

trait LowerPriorityBooleanConverter {
  implicit def any2bool = new BooleanConverter[AnyRef] {
    def apply(s: AnyRef) = s != null
  }
}

object BooleanConverter extends LowerPriorityBooleanConverter {

  implicit def num2bool[T: Numeric] = new BooleanConverter[T] {
    def apply(n: T) = implicitly[Numeric[T]].zero != n
  }

  // Note that this could catch String as well
  implicit def seq2bool[T <% GenTraversableOnce[_]] = new BooleanConverter[T] {
    def apply(s: T) = s != null && !s.isEmpty
  }

}

// This is similar to the original post
implicit class NonBooleanLogic[A](x: A) {

  // Note that we let the implicit converter determine the return type 
  // of the method
  def |||[B, C](y: => B)(
    // make sure we have implicits for both a converter and a boolean converter
    implicit converter: Converter[A, B, C], bool: BooleanConverter[A]): C =
    // do the actual conversion
    converter.convert(x, y)
}
```

The result with a few tests:

```
1 ||| 2                                       //> res0: Int = 1
(null: String) ||| "test"                     //> res1: String = test
1.0 ||| 2                                     //> res2: Double = 1.0
1 ||| 2.0                                     //> res3: Int = 1
List() ||| Seq("test")                        //> res4: Seq[String] = List(test)
1f ||| 2.0                                    //> res5: Float = 1.0
1f ||| 2f                                     //> res6: Float = 1.0
0f ||| 2.0                                    //> res7: Float = 2.0
0 ||| 2f                                      //> res8: Int = 2
2.0 ||| 2f                                    //> res9: Double = 2.0
2.0 ||| 3.0                                   //> res10: Double = 2.0
Seq("test") ||| List()                        //> res11: Seq[String] = List(test)
"" ||| "test"                                 //> res12: String = test
```

As you can see, in order to preserve types we need to use a specific pattern. I learned it from an answer to one of my own questions here: [How to define a method for which the returntype is based on types of argument and type parameter in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674125/how-to-define-a-method-for-which-the-returntype-is-based-on-types-of-argument-an/14674624#14674624)

The upside of this approach is that you could add specific converters for specific types without altering the original code.